# How to simulate user's click on the submit button in javascript when the "select" element changes?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've got a simple html form. I would like to simulate user's click on the submit button in javascript when the "select" element changes. 
So, I've tried to do that with the function onchange of the selects. I don't know how to write the function that would send the form. I have searched through this site,  but I did't find anything that would work for me. It simply didn't do anything. It did not send the form. Maybe I only needed to include something, but I didn't, so maybe if I did, it would work. I really don't know. I am new in javascript. I would be very thankful for a piece of java script code (the function) and maybe the CDN or file that I need, if I do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

//probably I need to include something here (if so, could you please send me the CDN?)

</head>
<body>


<form method="post" id="theForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<select id="year_start"  name="year_start" onchange="myFunction()"> 
    <option>2009</option>       
    <option>2010</option>       
    <option>2011</option>       
    <option>2012</option>       
    <option>2013</option>       
    <option>2014</option>       
    <option>2015</option>       
    <option>2016</option>       
    <option>2017</option>       
    <option>2018</option>       
  </select> 
<select id="month_start"  name="month_start" onchange="myFunction()"> 
    <option>January</option>       
    <option>February</option>       
    .
    .      
    <option>December</option>       
</select> 
 <select id="day_start" name="day_start" onchange="myFunction()" >
    <option>1</option>       
    <option>2</option>       
    .
    .
    .
    <option>30</option>       
    <option>31</option>       
  </select> 

  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">

</form>

<script>
function myFunction(){
//what should I do there? - I want to simulate user's click on the "submit" button
}
</script>

<?php

//I want to do some stuff there after some of the selects was changed
echo $POST['year_start'];
echo $POST['month_start'];
echo $POST['day_start'];

?>

</body>
```

Comment: Okay maybe im wrong but without an action attribute the form normally cannot be sended. If the answer of Terry is not working add the action attribute

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually triggering a `click` event on the submit button, why not call the `submit()` method on the form instead?

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
}
```

Since what you're using is just vanilla JS, you don't need to include any library: that's the beauty of writing vanilla JS.

Pro-tip: you might want to consider avoiding inline JS binding, and use `addEventListener` to check for the `change` event fired from the `<select>` elements (assuming that you want to bind to all `<select>` elements):

```
var formEl = document.getElementById('theForm');
var selectEls = formEl.querySelectorAll('select');

[].prototype.slice.call(selectEls).forEach(function(selectElement) {
    // Bind event listener to each select element
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
        formEl.submit();
    });
});
```

Otherwise, you can also use comma-separated ID selectors in your `querySelectorAll()` method, e.g.:

```
var selectEls = formEl.querySelectorAll('#year_start, #month_start, #day_start');
```

---

## Important note

Based on your comments, I have a feeling that you want the JS to perform some kind of action in the PHP code. Remember that **PHP is a server-side language**, so if you want to use JS to trigger some kind of server-state mutation via PHP, you will need to use AJAX.

---

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
var formEl = document.getElementById('theForm');
var selectEls = formEl.querySelectorAll('select');

Array.prototype.slice.call(selectEls).forEach(function(selectElement) {
  // Bind event listener to each select element
  selectElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // Here is just dummy code to show you how binding works
    console.log('Will submit form');
  
    // Uncommt this line to perform actual form submission
    //formEl.submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" id="theForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <select id="year_start" name="year_start">
    <option>2009</option>
    <option>2010</option>
    <option>2011</option>
    <option>2012</option>
    <option>2013</option>
    <option>2014</option>
    <option>2015</option>
    <option>2016</option>
    <option>2017</option>
    <option>2018</option>
  </select>
  <select id="month_start" name="month_start">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>December</option>
  </select>
  <select id="day_start" name="day_start">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>30</option>
    <option>31</option>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" id="submit_button">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but when I change the select, nothing happens. It only changes, it does not do my php stuff. I don't know where is the problem

Comment: @janka PHP runs on the server side, while JS runs on the client side. If you want to dynamically save the state of the form, you have to look into AJAX.

Comment: but, when I submit the form, doesn't it send my data to the server? When I manually click on the button, i does.

Comment: @janka That's because you have no `action` attribute in your `<form>` element.

Comment: okay, I understeand, I need to use AJAX, thank you. the "dummy code" works well, but when I uncommented the line to submit the form, I got the error: 
Uncaught TypeError: formEl.submit is not a functionat HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (date.php:88)
how do I soleve it, please?

Comment: @janka Ah, that's because you're using `input` of type `submit`, causing `formEl.submit` to point to the element instead of the form's native `submit()` method. To circumvent this issue, change the submit button to use `<button>`, i.e. `<button id="submit">Submit</button>`.

Comment: @janka Check if you have other `<input type="submit">` elements in the form.

Comment: no, I don't. the whole code looks like that what you can see in my question. (+ that one ..input type="submit".. I changed to <button id="submit">Submit</button>) + I deleted all onchange="myfunction".. simply used your code

Comment: @janka Sorry, my bad! If you change your ID to something other than `submit`, that should work ;) like `submit_button`. It clashes with the namespace for the form's native method.

Comment: yes, it works, thak you very much :) you solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.click()` function to click on the submit function from javascript.

```js
function myFunction(){
  document.getElementById('submit').click();
}
```

And avoid using inline functions in html.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is no other way than to create your own temporary button and simulate the click as a last resort.

```
const simulateSubmit = () => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')

    button.type = 'submit'
    document.body.appendChild(button)
    button.click()
    document.body.removeChild(button)
}
```

Instead of `document.body` use an element inside the form or the form itself.